# Disabling PictureBoxes until BackgroundWorker has completed AND/OR simpler way to do it

Tags: c#, winforms, background, worker

I have this program that is a game where the player has to match two images. (The images are just the font wingdings letters). The image is stored in a `PictureBox`, all `PictureBox`es have a default image and when the first image is clicked the image underneath will be revealed.

This `PictureBox` stays open until the player clicks a second `PictureBox` to see if it is a match with the first. If it is a match both boxes will show the player the image and the boxes will be disabled. If it isn't a match both boxes will return to their default image.

However there is a bug: if a third box is clicked while the two that aren't matches are opened (i.e three boxes are clicked in quick succession) the program will register that click and disable it without revealing the image and keep the two that aren't matches opened until until one of them is clicked.

The image below shows this (ignore the skull and snow flake images there matches I made before running into the bug). This is the program using a `foreach` loop to disable the boxes.

[image]

I exhausted all the obvious options such as using a `foreach` loop, disabling all boxes when it entered the `if` loop where it checks if they're matches etc.

I looked on Google then and came across the background worker option. I tried various methods using this but I could never get it working the way it was suppose to. The way it is sitting now is the last idea I had with it.

Forgive me if it is sitting badly and is far from what is needed to get it working the way I want, but the bug still remains…I put a `for` loop into the `DoWork` handler because you can't access the UI controls in this.

I had what is now in `RunWorkerCompleted` in the `DoWork` part, but it kept on freezing because of the reason above. This is the bug still in there with the `BackgroundWorker` option (see pic). I was under the impression that everything was disabled on a form until the work is complete and through that logic I shouldn't be able to click a third `PictureBox` until the other two have returned to their default image.

[image: pic]

```
//Code that for when one then two pictures are clicked
private void Picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Function with two      parameters passed in. 
    {

        Clicked_Picture = (Label)sender; //Sets the Clickd Picture to what ever picture was clicked.

        Number_of_Images++; //Sets number of images to 1.
        if (Number_of_Images < 3) //Should always go into this if statement
        {
            Clicked_Picture.Text = Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString(); //Setting the text equal to the tag

            if (Number_of_Images == 1) //Go in here if one image is clicked.
            {
                PlaySound.Play();
                Temp_Tag = Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString(); //Giving the tag string the value of clicked picture tag
                Temp_Pic = Clicked_Picture; //setting the temp pic equal to the cliked picture
                Clicked_Picture.Enabled = false; //Disabling clicked pic so it can't be clicked again so that the user can match

            }
            else if (Number_of_Images == 2) //On second picture click do this...
            {
                if (Temp_Tag != Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    PlayNoMatch = new SoundPlayer("NoMatch.wav");
                    PlayNoMatch.Play();
                    tmr_Delay.Enabled = true;
                    Temp_Pic.Enabled = true;//Renabling the picture that was first clicked.                  

                }
                else
                {
                    Clicked_Picture.Enabled = false;
                    if(!bgw_SecondPic.IsBusy)
                    {
                        bgw_SecondPic.RunWorkerAsync();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Wait");
                    }

                }
                Number_of_Images = 0;//Reset number of images clicked.
            }
        }
    }
```

Code of the `BackgroundWorker`:

```
private void bgw_SecondPic_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;
        while (count < 999999)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    private void bgw_SecondPic_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayMatch = new SoundPlayer("match.wav");
        PlayMatch.Play();
        Num_Correct++;
        lbl_Matches.Text = Num_Correct.ToString();
        Clicked_Picture.Enabled = false;
        Temp_Pic.Enabled = false;
        if (Num_Correct == 8)
        {
            tmr_counter.Stop();
            string minutes = Convert.ToString(x);
            string seconds = Convert.ToString(x + i);
            if (x < 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, all matches complete in " + seconds + " Seconds");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, all matches complete in " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds ");
            }

            RecordTimeToFile(minutes, seconds, name);

            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

UPDATE ORIGINAL AS REQUESTED:

```
private void Picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Function with two parameters passed in. 
    {

        Clicked_Picture = (Label)sender; //Sets the Clickd Picture to what ever picture was clicked.

        Number_of_Images++; //Sets number of images to 1.
        if (Number_of_Images < 3) //Should always go into this if statement
        {
            Clicked_Picture.Text = Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString(); //Setting the text equal to the tag

            if (Number_of_Images == 1) //Go in here if one image is clicked.
            {
                PlaySound.Play();
                Temp_Tag = Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString(); //Giving the tag string the value of clicked picture tag
                Temp_Pic = Clicked_Picture; //setting the temp pic equal to the cliked picture
                Clicked_Picture.Enabled = false; //Disabling clicked pic so it can't be clicked again so that the user can match

            }
            else if (Number_of_Images == 2) //On second picture click do this...
            {
                if (Temp_Tag != Clicked_Picture.Tag.ToString())
                {
                    PlayNoMatch = new SoundPlayer("NoMatch.wav");
                    PlayNoMatch.Play();
                    tmr_Delay.Enabled = true;
                    Temp_Pic.Enabled = true;//Renabling the picture that was first clicked.                  

                }
                else
                {
                    PlayMatch = new SoundPlayer("match.wav");
                    PlayMatch.Play();
                    Num_Correct++; // counting amount correct
                    lbl_Matches.Text = Num_Correct.ToString();
                    Clicked_Picture.Enabled = false; // disabling picture boxes that are correct match
                    Temp_Pic.Enabled = false;
                    if (Num_Correct == 8) // on game completeion do this..
                    {
                        tmr_counter.Stop();
                        string minutes = Convert.ToString(x);
                        string seconds = Convert.ToString(x + i);
                        if (x < 1)
                        { 
                            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, all matches complete in " + seconds + " Seconds"); 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Congratulations, all matches complete in " + minutes + " Minutes " + seconds + " Seconds "); 
                        }

                        RecordTimeToFile(minutes, seconds,name);

                        this.Close();
                    }
                }
                Number_of_Images = 0;//Reset number of images clicked.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given that the `BackgroundWorker` version did not address the bug satisfactorily, it would be better to not complicate your question by including the code that uses it. Instead, please post the original code, with the original bug. Also, please provide [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the issue. Yes, that's a non-trivial effort on your part. But without that, the only answers will be speculative, not necessarily helpful.

Comment: I didn't know if I was using the background worker correctly, and was curious to find out what way it would have to be coded into the background worker in order to get it working correctly so I could learn from this. I left the background worker in the question and have included the original as per your request.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of that BackgroundWorker and put everything back in your Picture_Click() method as it was originally.  Now, at the bottom of Picture_Click(), call `Application.DoEvents();`.  This should flush out any pending click events that occurred while that handler was running and prevent them running once the method exits:

```
private void Picture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Function with two      parameters passed in. 
{

    // ... all of your previous code ...

    Application.DoEvents(); // flush the queue before leaving this event
}
```

Note that for this to work you need to disable the Label, then call DoEvents() before re-enabling it.  Here's a bare bones example to demonstrate the difference:

```
    private int Number_of_Images;

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Enabled = false;

        Number_of_Images++; 
        label1.Text = "Clicks: " + Number_of_Images.ToString();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

        label1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Enabled = false;

        Number_of_Images++;
        label2.Text = "Clicks: " + Number_of_Images.ToString();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Application.DoEvents();

        label2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Click on label1/label2, then click on the same one several more times while it is disabled to see the difference.

Comment: IMHO, no correct answer will _ever_ propose calling `Application.DoEvents()`. It is too easy to introduce hidden re-entrancy into code that wasn't designed for it, causing any number of subtle, hard-to-fix bugs. It also doesn't even result in a responsive UI, especially not when you wait 3 seconds before actually calling it.

Comment: Seriously @PeterDuniho?  Of course it's not responsive, that's not the point or goal of the Sleep(), nor the DoEvents() call.  This is purposely NOT responsive to give you a chance to click on the Label a couple more times while the Label is disabled and **before** the method handler has had a chance to complete and exit.  It's purely illustrative and demonstrates the symptom described by the original author.  Try the example for yourself to see what it does.  Repeatedly click on label1; it keeps incrementing/pausing.  When you repeatedly click label2, though, it will ignore the extra clicks.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear: it's the call to `DoEvents()` that is the problem here. I understand the above is demo code (hence the `Sleep()`), but other people have the habit of copy/pasting whatever random code they happen across; even demo code needs to follow good practices. Anything you can solve with `DoEvents()`, can be solved better without.

Comment: Your suggestion is somewhat working. You sort of threw me off by seating labels, did you mean picture boxes? That's what I used in place of your label1. Anyways, the delay is working and it won't let me click any other pictures which is what I want. But on the second picture click it is not displaying the image underneath. It was before I implemented this code. Going to look into it to see if I can fix it...

Comment: Your code tells me you're using **Labels**: `Clicked_Picture = (Label)sender;`  You're casting the sender to a Label, not a PictureBox...which is it then?  If you really have PictureBoxes wired up to that handler then an exception would be occurring at run-time...